# Manually compute ARIMAX forecast

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, arima, autoregressive

I need to forecast a phenomenon using an autoregressive model with an exogenous variable. I've estimated an ARIMA(1,0,0) model, but I can't understand how the forecasts are calculated.

Below is the dataset and the code used

```
# History data
y <- c(NA, 18.53499, 18.45049, 18.50638, 18.56233, 18.57174, 18.57489, 18.65894, 18.73435, 18.74276, 18.89068, 18.86537, 18.90476, 18.86128, 18.89691, 18.93336, 18.99445, 18.93349, 18.97266, 18.99395, 19.04327, 19.09495, 19.20510, 19.22705, 19.23720, 19.30036)
X <- c(NA, 20.84371, 20.87513, 20.95040, 21.01817, 21.07814, 21.13471, 21.17879, 21.26326, 21.32649, 21.44111, 21.49291, 21.50877, 21.49673, 21.49891, 21.48236, 21.45077, 21.44423, 21.48529, 21.57711, 21.66768, 21.73942, 21.84075, 21.81733, 21.86867, 21.98712)

# Forecast data
y_pred <- c(rep(NA, 10))
X_pred <- c(22.12033, 22.18879, 22.24636, 22.30394, 22.36263, 22.40278, 22.44473, 22.49994, 22.56897, 22.64044)

# Convert to ts object
history_data <- ts(cbind(y, X), start = 1998, end = 2022)
pred_data <- ts(cbind(y_pred, X_pred), start=2023)

# Estimate ARIMAX(1,0,0)
arima_model <- arima(
    x=history_data[, "y"],
    order=c(1,0,0),
    xreg = history_data[, "X"],
    include.mean=TRUE
)
```

[image: Model summary]

The issue arises at the time of predictions. I have realized that the coefficients, multiplied by the autoregressive component and the exogenous component, do not match the forecast used by the predict function. I can't figure out what I am doing wrong or what the model code is doing without explicitly stating it!

Below are the values returned by the forecast and the calculation of the first prediction point done manually.

```
# Model forecast
pred_arima <- predict(arima_model, newxreg=pred_data[, "X_pred"])
pred_arima$pred
# A Time Series: 19.4091463551622 19.4598067255605 19.5024085006676 19.5450176757704 etc

# Manual forecast for the first forecast point
# 3.02318504045974 + 0.54237200749617 * 19.30036 + 0.739999567606275 * 22.12033 = 29.8601946743666
```

I'm seeking help because if I calculate the forecast manually, I get significantly different values (For the first point and also for the subsequent ones): 19.4091463551622 (from the model) vs 29.8601946743666 (calculated manually). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Your manual computation computes an ARIMAX forecast. Unfortunately, that is not what `arima()` models. Rather, [`arima()` models and forecasts a regression with ARIMA errors](https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/arimax/).

So what you need to do is to calculate the OLS fit for your simple linear regression both in-sample and for the forecast period, calculate the in-sample residuals, then forecast the last residual out using the fitted AR(1) parameter, finally add the OLS forecast and the AR(1) forecast for the residuals.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I still have some doubts. I interpreted the answer in this way:
1) I estimate an OLS model with only the exogenous variable and a constant, obtain the residuals of the regression 2) I estimate an AR(1) model without intercept using the series of residuals obtained in step 1. 3) I add the predictions obtained in step 1 and those obtained in step 2 to get the overall forecast of my ARIMAX model. Is what I understood correct? I've tried running some tests, and while the results are closer, they still slightly differ compared to what the `pred` function returns in R.

Comment: Yes, that is what should be happening. Are "slight" differences on the order of machine accuracy? (Note that the printed values are slightly different from the unrounded values used internally - use the internal ones.) It might be best to step through the calculation done in `predict.Arima` (note the capital `A`).

Comment: It is becoming increasingly clear that the answer you provided, for which I thank you very much, is correct. However, I believe the difference is not solely due to machine accuracy. Below is the distance between the forecasted values calculated and those resulting from ARIMA model: 1)0.008803487 || 2)0.005454998  || 3)0.004975241  || 4)0.005817646  || 5)0.007239596  || 6)0.008316371  ||  7)0.009541358  || 8)0.011212480  || 9)0.013324457  || 10)0.015518001. It's unfortunate that you can't directly estimate an ARIMAX and, as a result, don't have a quick interpretation of the coefficients.

Comment: Hm. Unfortunately, I don't have the time right now to help you in a deep dive, I am sorry. Have you tried stepping through `predict.Arima`? Also, the interpretation issue is exactly what Rob Hyndman says was the reason to use a regression with ARIMA errors rather than an ARIMAX model in the first place, because in ARIMAX, the "regression" coefficients get badly confounded with the ARIMA ones, and very hard to understand.